# Subclassing the Promise built-in using extends

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-class, cancellation

I want to add a `cancel` method to a subclass of the `Promise` built-in. Why does this not work?

```js
class CancellablePromise extends Promise {
    constructor(executor) {
        let cancel = null
        super((resolve,reject) => {
            cancel = reject
            executor(resolve, reject)
        })
        this.cancel = cancel
    }
}

const p = new CancellablePromise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
    .then(() => console.log('success'))
    .catch((err) => console.log('rejected', err))

p.cancel() // Uncaught exception
```

Is the answer todo with `Symbol.species`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `then`, `catch`, and `finally` create and return a **new** promise, and the new promise that they create and return doesn't have the `cancel` method on it.

To fix that, you'd have to override `then` so it copies `cancel` from the current instance to the new one:

```js
class CancellablePromise extends Promise {
    constructor(executor) {
        let cancel = null;
        super((resolve,reject) => {
            cancel = reject;
            executor(resolve, reject);
        });
        this.cancel = cancel;
    }

    then(onFulfilled, onRejected) {
        const p = super.then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
        p.cancel = this.cancel;
        return p;
    }
}

const p = new CancellablePromise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
    .then(() => console.log('success'))
    .catch((err) => console.log('rejected', err));

p.cancel();
```

You don't need to do `catch` or `finally`, they're both defined using calls to `then` (per specification).

I should note that there are a lot of nuances around cancellable promises that I haven't gotten into in detail. It may be worth a deep read of [Domenic Denicola's old (now withdrawn) cancellable promises proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-cancelable-promises) and [this article](https://medium.com/@benlesh/promise-cancellation-is-dead-long-live-promise-cancellation-c6601f1f5082) by Ben Lesh.

Comment: and not forgetting that not all "thenables" are necessarily instantiated from the `Promise` class.

Comment: @Alnitak - Indeed yes. My practice is to ensure that anything that may just be a thenable goes through `Promise.resolve` sooner rather than later. :-)

Comment: Inheritance is so fraught with accidental complexity, it's a deceptively advanced feature is  it not?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the `then` method returns a new instance of the current promise class, so the `p.cancel` method will be defined on the returned promise, but it refers to the last promise in the chain (the `catch` chain).
Canceling a promise is much more difficult than just rejecting the first promise in the chain. At the very least, you need to reject the deepest pending promise in the chain and clean up internal long term operations like requests, streams, setTimeout, etc.
They should look something like this:

```
import CPromise from "c-promise2";

const delay= (ms, value)=>{
    return new CPromise((resolve, reject, {onCancel}) => {
        const timer = setTimeout(resolve, ms, value);    
        onCancel(() => {
            log(`clearTimeout`);
            clearTimeout(timer);
        })
    })
}

const p= delay(1000, 123).then(console.log);

p.cancel();
```